# How to set a tooltip on a portion of String text?

Tags: java, components

what I want is to set a tooltip to a portion of text inside a Jtextpane document.

What I am doing now is to insert the first portion of text with jTextPaneDoc.insertString into the jtextpane. And adding the second part also with the same insertstring method but I want the second portion to have a tooltip.

I know I can easily do that by adding the second text portion into a jtextfield and set the tootltip on the jtextfield but this solution result to alignment issue. And also I would not be able to select the entire text as the jtextfield will not be selectable with the text.

The picture shows that the string text and the jtextfield are not aligned

[image: picture]

Is there a way to add a tooltip to something not a component (like string) in Java?

Thanks to help

Comment: Hello, can somebody help me here please? if my request it was not clear for you please ask me for clarification